# Find the first and last index of each coordinate in a list of coordinates using MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I have a list of coordinates (x,y) and I need to find the index of the first and last occurrence of each coordinate in the list.
Example (in my use-cast I have ~30M coordinates):

```
x = [1 3 7 1 3];
y = [5 1 6 5 1];
first = [1 2 3 1 2];
last  = [4 5 3 4 5];
```

I implemented it using a Matrix and a loop, it looks like this, but it is slow:

```
x1 = min(x);
y1 = min(y);
x2 = max(x);
y2 = max(y);
tic
Mlast = zeros(y2-y1+1, x2-x1+1);
Mfirst = Mlast;

ind = sub2ind(size(Mlast),y-y1+1, x-x1+1);

for i1=1:length(ind)
    first = Mfirst(ind(i1));

    if first == 0
        first = i1;
    end

    Mlast(ind(i1)) = i1;
    Mfirst(ind(i1)) = first;
end
```

I tried to vectorize the whole process, but I only succeed with Mlast:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(Mlast),y-y1+1, x-x1+1);
t = (1:length(x))';
Mlast(ind) = t;
Mfirst = ???
```

Is there a way to get this for the first occurrence as well?

Comment: `find(x==y, 1, 'first')` finds the first entry upholding the criterion. Other useful functions might be `unique()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function can do that:

```
[~, b, c] = unique([x(:) y(:)], 'rows', 'first');
first = b(c).';
[~, b, c] = unique([x(:) y(:)], 'rows', 'last');
last = b(c).';
```

Comment: Indeed it works, but it is approx. 20x slower than the version with the loop

Comment: Weird; I would have expected `unique` to be pretty fast

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that coordinates are positive integers and specially when the range of coordinates is small you can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
x1 = min(x);
y1 = min(y);
x2 = max(x);
y2 = max(y);
sz = [y2-y1+1, x2-x1+1];
ind = sub2ind(sz,y-y1+1, x-x1+1);

ifirst = accumarray(ind(:), 1:numel(ind), [], @min);
ilast  = accumarray(ind(:), 1:numel(ind), [], @max);
Mfirst = ifirst(ind);
Mlast  = ilast(ind);
```

For higher ranges you can use the sparse option:

```
ifirst = accumarray(ind(:), 1:numel(ind), [], @min,[],1);
ilast  = accumarray(ind(:), 1:numel(ind), [], @max,[],1);
```

Comment: It works! But it is approximately 30x slower than the implementation with the loop. But interesting to learn about accumarray...

Answer (score 1):

If you've got 30M points then you likely don't have enough memory for this method... but it's pretty quick for smaller arrays

```
x = [1 3 7 1 3];
y = [5 1 6 5 1];

xy = cat( 3, x, y );

chk = all( xy == permute( xy, [2 1 3] ), 3 );

[~,first] = max( chk );
[~,last] = max( flipud( chk ) );
last = size(chk,1) - last + 1;
```

---

**Edit** You can also do this with `findgroups`, and looping over the unique coordinates instead of each coordinate to have a potentially much shorter loop...

```
x = [1 3 7 1 3];
y = [5 1 6 5 1];

g = findgroups( x, y );   
first = zeros( size( x ) );
last = first;
for ii = 1:max(g)
    idx = (ii==g);
    first( idx ) = find( idx, 1, 'first' );
    last( idx ) = find( idx, 1, 'last' );
end
```

---

**Edit2** I think these are both pretty slow relative to other answers here...